# php rename error: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

Tags: php

```
<?php
$dir = opendir('C:\Users\Prometheus\Desktop\milkmaid');
$i = 1;
// loop through all the files in the directory
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $newName = $i.'.mp4';
        $oldname = $file;
        rename($oldname, $newName);
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

when i run above script, i am getting following error:

> The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

Comment: Have you tried printing the names? I bet there is a path-separator missing.

Comment: `echo $newName;` gives `Resource id #41.mp4`

Comment: @tkausl i just updated my code, i am still seeing the same error. `echo $newName;` gives `1.mp4` while `echo $oldname;` gives `papa.mp4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$dir` is not a string. You can't concatenate `$file` with it. You will need to put the directory in a separate variable, and not forget to put a `/` in between directory and filename.

Comment: this is also not working: `<?php
$dir = opendir('C:\Users\Prometheus\Desktop\milkmaid');
$i = 1;
// loop through all the files in the directory
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $newName = $i.'.mp4';
  $oldname = $file;
  rename($oldname, $newName);
        $i++;
    }
}
?>`

Comment: You're probably trying to rename from a different directory.

Comment: @TarunMahashwari you are not using an absolute path in either argument in rename().

Comment: @TarunMahashwari you should really try to learn basic troubleshooting skills. rename() doesn't work? Echo what you are passing rename. It should have been immediately obvious how wrong the arguments were and still are.

Comment: oh my god, you are so right dear @Evert, yes $dir is not a string, i just change my code, please help me out, still i am getting same error.

Comment: @TarunMahashwari the arguments are still non-absolute and wrong. I'm not writing down the solution for you. All the information is there.

Comment: Dear @Evert thanks for all the help you provide to me, i am giving you an upvote for this.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `$dir` in the `rename()` works for me

```
<?php
$dir = opendir('C:\Users\Prometheus\Desktop\milkmaid');
$i = 1;
// loop through all the files in the directory
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $newName = $i.'.mp4';
        $oldname = $file;
        rename($dir.$oldname, $dir.$newName);
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This worked great. Should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this :-

```
$directory = '/public_html/testfolder/';
$i=1;
    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) { 
        while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {     
            $newName = $i.'.mp4';
            rename($directory . $fileName, $directory . $newName);
            $i++:
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
$dir = 'D:\files'; //path of folder
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) 
{
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        if($fileName != '.' && $fileName != '..')
        {
            $newName = $counter . " - " . $fileName;
            rename($dir."/".$fileName, $dir."/".$newName);
            $counter++;
        }

    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```